# Quantified Propositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been trying to translate the following sentences into quantified propositions by making sure I state all propositional functions that I use and any assumptions that I make.

Can you see if I'm on the right track here?

1. All engineers are good with computers.

   Let $E(x)$ be '$x$ is an engineer' and $C(x)$ be '$x$ is good with computers,'
   where the domain of $x$ is all people in the world.

   Then, $\forall x\ E(x) \rightarrow C(x)$.
2. Some mathematicians also like poetry.

   Let $M(x)$ be '$x$ is a mathematician' and $P(x)$ be '$x$ also likes poetry,' where the  domain of $x$ is all people in the world.

   Then, $\exists x\ M(x) \land P(x)$.
3. There are no writers who do not like reading books.

   Let $W(x)$ be '$x$ is a writer' and $B(x)$ be '$x$ likes reading books,' where the  domain of $x$ is all people in the world.

   Then, $\neg\ \exists x\ W(x) \land \neg B(x)$.
4. Not every athlete is famous.

   Let $A(x)$ be '$x$ is an athlete' and $F(x)$ be '$x$ is famous,' where the  domain of $x$ is all people in the world.

   Then, $\neg \forall x\ A(x) \rightarrow F(x)$.
5. Only scientists properly value civilisation.

   Let $S(x)$ be '$x$ is a scientist' and $C(x)$ be '$x$ properly values civilisation,' where the  domain of $x$ is all people in the world.

   Then, $\forall x\ C(x) \rightarrow S(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with number 4!
It should be
$$ \exists x \; A(x) \wedge \neg F(x) $$

Of course I mean, before your edit was made!

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to put the negation symbol before the universal quantifier. I was wondering if my logical expression is closer to the original English sentence, though?